# Scale an openCV algorithm to large scale e.g. a mobile app

Tags: android, ios, opencv

I have a computationally expensive algorithm which identifies and label videos implemented in openCV. Now I need to, let's say, roll out this solution to public for example in the form of a web application where you upload the video and get the results or a mobile app. The computations are expensive I can't possible have these computations on local mobile device.

Can anybody please guide me in the right direction? I don't even know where to start or even what to Google.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a rather complex goal to achieve if you don't even know where to start. Split it up into smaller achievable steps. Learn about client-server model, learn about web applications. Implement that for a single user, one task at a time. Next, scale it to multiple users on a single server, learning as you go. When you can do that (and have solid understanding of what you're doing), you can start to focus on scaling this up further.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have a little experience with web development, and I have an idea how does that work. I was wondering how exactly this should be possible. Google cloud, AWS, any starting pointer would be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Just point me in the right direction, so I am not just throwing arrows blindfoldedly.